# Forcing a line break in a string in HTML, Equivalent to \n in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is being used in a Bootstrap Popover.

The live page under development can be viewed [here](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/cover.html)

This is got to be simple but I can't find it anywhere. Within data-content attribute I want to force a paragraph or line break between "Date Assessed: 10-Nov-13 and Results: CR= ... 
Using a BR or P tag doesn't work it shows the literal tag. In Javascript to force a line break you use \n how do you do the same in HTML within a quoted string?

```
     <td class="setWidth concat"><div class="boldTitle"><a href="#" 
     class="tip"  rel="popover" data-trigger="hover"  
     data-placement="top" 

     data-content="Date Assessed: 10-Nov-13 <br /> 
     Results: Cr = 2.2 mg/dl" 

        data-original-title="Out of Range">
          <span style="color:red"  
       class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> &nbsp; Cr = 2.2 mg/dL</a></div></td>
```

Comment: Where do you want to display this line break? Are you expecting a break line in DOM? @___@

Comment: between "Date Assessed: 10-Nov-13 and Results: CR= ... As you can see I have a <BR /> tag there.

Comment: My question is, how are you planning to see this line break? while inspecting the dom? or in some textarea or so?

Comment: This is in a bootstrap popover.

Comment: Mentioning it in the question and tagging `bootstrap` would help others understand the problem, don't you think?

Comment: Perhaps but the question is generic. How do you create HTML styles within an HTML string?

Comment: No it's not. in simple html string `<br>` will break line. Have you tried `\n` ?

Comment: See the subject title, yes I've tried \n and

data-id="Some text here that is long and you want to force a break" is a SIMPLE string.

Comment: It's not just a generic question, because bootstrap is the one reading that `data-content` and giving you the wrong output.  This doesn't have to do with HTML, this has to do with the specific javascript code that bootstrap is using to output the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See last update:  Bootstrap gives you ability to specify that the content is HTML instead of text.

It depends entirely on bootstrap's implementation of the popover effect.  If they are using `$('.popover').html($(this).data('content'))` then it should "just work".  If they are using `$('.popover').text($(this).data('content'))` or otherwise escaping the results of the `data-attribute` first, then it probably won't.

If bootstrap's implementation isn't working the way you want it to work, you might be served better by writing your own javascript to handle the effect you're looking for.

See this fiddle for an example of a line break from a `data-attribute` working correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/g32tw/1/

Update:  I've updated the fiddle with a second link that produces the error you're experiencing, which is likely how bootstrap's implementation works.

UPDATE:  just looked at bootstrap's documentation.  Have you tried adding `"data-html" = "true"` to the element?

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage

Watch out with this - if the content is end-user-supplied using the `html` option might subject you to XSS attack vulnerabilities.  If you trust the data it's fine.  See https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/ for information about cross-site scripting.

Comment: Can this be done for on hover? I've posted a live link.

Comment: Well of course it can, just use the `hover` event instead of the `click` event: http://jsfiddle.net/g32tw/2/  However, you might want to consult the bootstrap documentation for how to programatically make that popover appear...

Comment: See my newest update... it looks like bootstrap gives you the option to use HTML instead of Text so you don't have to roll your own version  of the code.

Comment: Easy to do line breaks bold, etc. but what about changes in font color?

Comment: What do you mean changes in font color?  Since you can put any HTML you want in there, you can add classes and style them with CSS.

Comment: Trickier than you think since you can't use quotes!

Comment: Sure you can!  You can just use single-quotes for the html attribute and double-quotes for the content.  That's the easiest way.  There's a way to escape the quotes too... I forget exactly.  It might just be `\"`  But I'd test the mixed-quote strategy first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can.  You could try to have two data items:

```
data-assessdate="Date Assessed: 10-Nov-13" 
data-results="Cr = 2.2 mg/dl"
```

and reassemble afterward with Javascript before displaying:

```
var summary = this.dataset;
var newhtml=summary.assessdate . "<br />" . summary.results;
```

and then write `newhtml` to the DOM where ever you want.